# Difference between "close" and "flag"

Tags: support, policy, flagging, vote-to-close

On questions, I have the possibility to vote for "close" (as duplicate, say), or to "flag" (as duplicate). Does is it make a difference?

Comment: I don’t think that is true. When you gain the privilege to vote to close, you can’t flag a question *for something that’s a closing reason* anymore. If you try to flag something e.g. as a dupe, the dialog will stealthily become a vote-to-close dialog. The flags for ♦ moderator attention, spam, and not welcome remain untouched.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, the site is intended to work as a community, so using your votes is the preferred way to push for closing. Flagging is best used for things that really need moderator attention, which is more likely to be true for older questions which might not attract other people's interest than for very recent posts that will (probably) get other close votes.

---

One point to note is that mods can migrate to anywhere on the StackExchange network. So if you spot a question off-topic for us but on-topic for another site on the network, flagging (in addition to voting) is a good idea.